# Alternativa a kbhit

Tags: c++

Ando practicando con un curso de creacion de "videojuegos" y usan la funcion kbhit de la libreria conio. Me he planteado si hay alguna forma de evitar usar esa libreria y usar alguna alternativa o equivalencia.

Comment: Esta pregunta clama por un cierre `basada en opiniones`. La lectura de teclas *físicas* depende del Sistema Operativo, y hay **multitud** de librerías que lo *abstraen* para hacer esa tarea mas *portable*.

Comment: @Trauma he estado buscando información de la STD y no encuentro nada. Todos hacen referencia a conio, y en Linux a ncurses.

Comment: **No** lo vas a encontrar en la `std`. Hay que usar librerías externas. Prácticamente **todas** las que están pensadas para videojuegos tienen su propia versión de `kbhit`.

Comment: @Trauma pero esa librería ha tenido que ser escrita en c anteriormente para dar esa facilidad... hay alguna forma de simular el kbhit mediante código std?

Comment: Son llamadas exclusivas para cada Sistema Operativo: un código para Windows, otro para Linux, otro para Mac, ... Mira, por ejemplo, para Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar ¿qué es `kbhit`?

#### `kbhit`.

Es una función [POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), [**obsoleta**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) de las librerías de [c](/questions/tagged/c) que indica si se está pulsando alguna tecla devolviendo un valor diferente de `0` en caso afirmativo.

#### Alternativas.

No existe ninguna alternativa portable en C++ para la lectura de teclado. Esto significa que debes acceder a rutinas dependientes del sistema operativo para comprobar el estado de las teclas o usar una librería de terceros.